# How can I center exactly the list items on the nav?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to center everything. I can't understand what causes the space on the sides to be unequal:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid pink;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #143774;
  font-family: lora;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 3.375;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: solid blue;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid red;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <logo>
      <h1> Living the simple life</h1>
      <p> a blog exploring minimalism in life</p>
    </logo>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about me</li>
        <li>recent posts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: use `space-between` not `space-around`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `space-between` on your `ul` flex display and remove the default padding from `ul` and remove the margin you set on the `li`.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid pink;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #143774;
  font-family: lora;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 3.375;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid blue;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <logo>
      <h1> Living the simple life</h1>
      <p> a blog exploring minimalism in life</p>
    </logo>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about me</li>
        <li>recent posts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16496357/kameron

Actually apply padding to the ul, solved the problem.
So the ul has a default padding, didnt know that

Comment: i did upvoting  and also marked your answer as the one who helped me

Answer (score 1):

Your list items *are* center-aligned, but the labels are different lengths, so there's uneven space alongside.

It sounds like you want then entire list centered instead of each item. To have equal padding on the sides, use `space-between` instead of `space-around` and set padding on the list.

You'll notice, however, that this leaves things out of balance visually because now the middle item is shifted to one side. Your original layout may be better.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid pink;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #143774;
  font-family: lora;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 3.375;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* <-- updated */
  border: solid blue;
  padding: 0 30px; /* <-- specific padding value */
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid red;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <logo>
      <h1> Living the simple life</h1>
      <p> a blog exploring minimalism in life</p>
    </logo>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about me</li>
        <li>recent posts</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```